# module 'tensorflow.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'legacy'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am getting the above-mentioned error while trying to import
from official. nlp.configs import encoders
from tensorflow_ranking.extension.premade import tfrbert_task
for resume ranking for job description

I tried installing tensorflow==2.9 but it doesn't works.

Comment: Could you please format the Question properly? The code is not illegible.

Comment: I am trying to use tfr bert for ranking resumes with the job descriptions but I was not able to import  tensorflow_ranking.extension.premade import tfrbert_task but now I figured out that I have to clone tensorflow repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use this class directly, but instead instantiate one of its subclasses such as tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD, tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam, etc.

This is the default Keras optimizer base class until v2.10 (included). In v2.11 and later, tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer points to a new base class implementation. The legacy class won't be deleted in the future and will continue to be available at tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Optimizer.

More details here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/legacy/Optimizer